# How can we use dynamic SQL to pull data from Teradata using Python to execute the query?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, teradata

I have a query that looks like this.

```
query_exp = """SELECT *
               FROM MASTER_TBLS.EXP 
               WHERE PROJECT_TYPE_ID IN ('109926',
                                        '103471',
                                        '120135')"""
```

In reality, I have a little over 18k numbers in PROJECT_TYPE_CD, so it's a bit unwieldly to use. In SQL Server I could create a dynamic SQL statement and pass that to the DB engine to execute, bu t in the Teradata world, I don't know how to do this. Also, this is running in a Jupyter Notebook, so somehow, I need to get Python to do the call to Teradata.

In Python, the first thing I do is get all unique IDs, like this.

```
unique_ID = df_exp.PROJECT_TYPE_ID.unique()
unique_ID = pd.DataFrame(unique_ID)
```

I think I'm ok with the Python stuff, but I really don't know how to create the dynamic SQL in Teradata.

Comment: With that many values in the IN clause, it would be more efficient to upload the dataframe to a temporary table and join. Have you checked out the Teradata Vantage modules for Jupyter? https://teradata.github.io/jupyterextensions

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out first thing tomorrow.

Comment: What are you trying to do that is dynamic?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I would upload all numbers into a holder table using bteq or fastload, and run the sql as "where project_type_id in (select project_type_id from holder_table)"